# Determining locations that contain multiple raster attribute types within a set distance

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, distance, proximity

In ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0:

I have a raster dataset of land cover type (LANDFIRE.gov), where each cell is assigned one of many possible land cover types (strings) in the EVT_NAME attribute column.

I'd like to identify all locations on the map that contain 3 specific land cover types within a 0.5km radius of one another. (e.g. Developed-Roads, Great Plains Prairie Pothole, and Developed-High Intensity all within 0.5km of one another). I don't care too much whether the output is a set of points, polygons, or a raster dataset, as long as I can easily visualize these locations on the map.

[image: map attribute table for the raster dataset. here, colors correspond to the EVT_NAME (land cover type) value]

Comment: Sounds like you want a neighborhood analysis: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/neighborhood-analysis-sample-applications.htm

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the Focal Statistics tool, here is some ESA landcover data:

[image: Input raster]

Run it through Focal Statistics, using the **Variety** type as shown below:

[image: Tool]

You get this:

[image: Results]

Each pixel is recording the number of different types of land cover within 500m of it.

*Be aware the input raster had to be in a coordinate system in metres.*

You can use this dataset and set all pixels not equal to 3 to NODATA, if that is what you need?

Comment: This is great, thank you. I had to remove the land cover types I was not interested in first (by using the raster remap function), but then this approach did exactly what I needed.